# cURL call on same server causes issue

Tags: php, curl

We are making cURL call from site a.com to site b.com
these  both sites are hosted on the same server.
Above scenario make server too much loaded.

Actually a.com was on server 1 and b.com was on server 2.
We were doing cURL call to b.com from a.com, due to hosted on different server it was taking time. So I thought to reduce serve time I put both site on same server.

And now it is facing drastic server load increase.

Does this has any relation with cURL I am making.

Comment: Look like you have done either lot of requests or some very heavy resource hungry request.

Comment: might be this would be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149838/intermittent-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error

Answer (score 0):

Are you in control of the server yourself?

You could try to add a record to the `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1 a.com
127.0.0.1 b.com
```